# Python 2.7 in anaconda: cannot import yahoo finance data with panda

Tags: python, pandas

I am  trying to import a basic stock quote using panda in python 2.7.

Any help on why this code will not work?

The error I get is: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas_datareader import data

data.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', '2016-06-01', '2016-10-26')
```

Comment: Can you paste the either error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
In [1]: import pandas_datareader.data as web

In [2]: import datetime

In [3]: start = datetime.datetime(2016, 06, 01)

In [4]: end = datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 26)

In [5]: f = web.DataReader('F', 'yahoo', start, end)
```